# How to visualise data from Scrapy scraped data

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I made a web scraper with Scrapy that collects exchange rate data from https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange_rates/html/index.en.html, and displays the data (Currency abbreviated name, Currency full name, and Rate) in a table through My SQL. What I want to do is make it so every time a rate goes up or down compared to the last scrape, there will be a column added to the currency, saying how many percent it increased or decreased. How would I do this? This is the code I have so far:

currency_scraper.py:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import EurotocurrencyItem

class CurrencySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'currency'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange_rates/html/index.en.html'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        exchange_rates = response.xpath('//*[@class="forextable"]//tr')
        for exchange_rate in exchange_rates:
            item = EurotocurrencyItem()
            currency = exchange_rate.xpath('.//td[@class="currency"]//text()').extract_first()
            currencyl = exchange_rate.xpath('.//td[@class="alignLeft"]//text()').extract_first()
            rate = exchange_rate.css('.rate::text').extract_first()

            item['currency'] = currency
            item['currencyl'] = currencyl
            item['rate'] = rate

            yield item
```

items.py:

```
import scrapy


class EurotocurrencyItem(scrapy.Item):
    currency = scrapy.Field()
    currencyl = scrapy.Field()
    rate = scrapy.Field()
```

pipelines.py:

```
import mysql.connector


class EurotocurrencyPipeline:

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='notrealpassword',
            database='currency'
        )
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS currency_tb""")
        self.curr.execute("""create table currency_tb(
                    currency text,
                    currencyl text,
                    rate text
                    )""")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        return item

    def store_db(self, item):
        self.curr.execute("""insert into currency_tb values(%s, %s, %s  )""", (
            item['currency'],
            item['currencyl'],
            item['rate']
        ))
        self.conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

A few possibilities:

- In the process_item method (which will be executed for every item), you can run a query against mysql to get back the previous exchange rate of the currency. You can then compare it to the rate in your item, and then do an insert
- You add a method open_spider in the pipeline, in which you query all of the current exchange rate per currency in a dictionary. In process_item you then compare the rate in the dictionary for the currency, to the rate in the current item. This way you only need to do 1 select in the database
- You change your database structure so you always insert a value every time you scrape. The logic of calculating decreases/increases can then be done outside of the scraping logic.